# Pass all *.txt files to a Python script in parallel

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

I have a Python script that takes a .txt file and does something with it. I need a Linux shell command that will search for .txt files throughout the system and pass the .txt files to my Python script. I guess with `xargs` I can run a process for a file to speed up the program. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
find / -type f -name "*\.txt" -exec script.py '{}' \;
```

would run script.py on every txt file in or below / , resulting in as many invocations of your script as there are files found.

Now, if you want to pass multiple found files to your script simultaneously, you can do:

```
find / -type f -name "*\.txt" -exec script.py '{}' +
```

From the **find(1) man page**:

> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command  on  the 
>   selected files,  but  the command line is built by appending each
>   selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the
>   command will be much less than the  number  of matched files.  The
>   command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its
>   command lines [...]

You can obviously achieve the same thing with xargs, but the syntax is less concise, which is why I would prefer using find's -exec action.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do is:

```
find . -type f -name "*\.txt" | parallel python myscript.py
```

It will run one job per cpu core.